# Parse Tag Content directly into Python Classes with Doxygen

Tags: xml-parsing, doxygen

So I want to make a python software that, automatically, extracts the tags of comments inside a .h file and parses them directly into python classes.
I'm currently using Doxygen to output the tags into a .xml file. The problem is that the .xml file is dynamic which makes it difficult to read.

- What is the best strategy that I can use to make a dynamic and
  reliable .xml reader?
- Is there already a tool that does this?
- Is Doxygen even the most appropriate tool to parse the tags?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: I will provide examples to better clarify my problem

Let's start with a header file

```
/**----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*
* @file LIBC_String.h
*
* @copyright Random
*
* @brief This class defines several functions to manipulate C strings and
* memory.
*
*/
#ifndef _LIBC_STRING_H_
#define _LIBC_STRING_H_


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Include Section:
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "LIBC_basictypes.h"

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Define Section:
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Typedef Section:
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Prototype Section:
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
*
* @brief This function copies a string.
*
* @author Random
*
* @pre  NA
*
* @post NA
*
* @param [out]  dest 'int8_t*'      Represents the destination string.
*
* @param [in]   src 'const int8_t*' Represents the string to be copied.
*
* @return 'int8_t' Pointer to the destination string.
*
* @constraints
* - The destination memory area and source memory area should not overlap.
* - The destination memory area should be large enough to contain the 'src'
* string.
* - The destination memory area should be in modifiable storage space and
* within the address space of the program.
* - The *src* should be a NULL terminated string.
* - The *src* and *dest* pointers should not be NULL.
* - This function is only available if FEATURE_LIBC_LEGACY_STR_ENABLED and
* FEATURE_LIBC_UNSAFE_STR_ENABLED symbols are defined.
*
* @req LIBC_strcpy shall copy the string pointed by *src* into the array
* pointed by *dest*, including the terminating NULL character.
* @derived FALSE
*
* @req LIBC_strcpy shall return a pointer to *dest*.
* @derived FALSE
*/
int8_t* LIBC_strcpy(int8_t* dest, const int8_t* src);

/**
*
* @brief This function concatenate strings.
*
* @author Random
*
* @pre  NA
*
* @post NA
*
* @param [out]  dst 'int8_t*'   Represents the string to where the characters
*                               are appended.
*
* @param [in]   src 'const int8_t*'     Represents the string from where the
*                                       characters are copied.
*
* @return 'int8_t*' Pointer to the destination string.
*
* @constraints
* - The destination memory area should be large enough to contain the
* concatenated resulting string, including the additional NULL character.
* - The destination memory area and source memory area should not overlap.
* - The destination memory area should be in modifiable storage space and
* within the address space of the program.
* - The *src* and *dst* pointers should not be NULL.
* - The *src* should be a NULL terminated string.
* - This function is only available if FEATURE_LIBC_LEGACY_STR_ENABLED and
* FEATURE_LIBC_UNSAFE_STR_ENABLED symbols are defined.
*
* @req LIBC_strcat shall append the string pointed by *src* (including the
* terminating NULL character) to the end of the string pointed by *dst*.
* @derived FALSE
*
* @req The initial character of *src* shall overwrite the existing
* terminating NULL character of *dst*.
* @derived TRUE
* @rationale This function concatenates the src and dest strings  
* in a single string without any separation.
*
* @req LIBC_strcat shall return a pointer to *dst*.
*
*/
int8_t* LIBC_strcat(int8_t* dst, const int8_t* src);
```

With this header file I have to get tag content like:

- Author
- Params for every function
- Return for every function
- Etc...

This content will have to be stored in Python Classes. I made a python algorithm that parses the xml output but it is not dynamic, meaning that it only works with this header file.
This header file will output the following xml files with doxygen

[image: Doxygen Output]

I'm assuming that I have to use the LIBC__String_8h.xml file
This file has the following structure:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<doxygen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="compound.xsd" version="1.9.4" xml:lang="en-US">
  <compounddef id="LIBC__String_8h" kind="file" language="C++">
    <compoundname>LIBC_String.h</compoundname>
    <includes local="yes">LIBC_basictypes.h</includes>
    <incdepgraph>
      <node id="1">
        <label>LIBC_String.h</label>
        <link refid="LIBC__String_8h"/>
        <childnode refid="2" relation="include">
        </childnode>
      </node>
      <node id="2">
        <label>LIBC_basictypes.h</label>
      </node>
    </incdepgraph>
      <sectiondef kind="func">
      <memberdef kind="function" id="LIBC__String_8h_1aedec0de3ce73e0b5d9c062c402f96a8b" prot="public" static="no" const="no" explicit="no" inline="no" virt="non-virtual">
        <type>int8_t *</type>
        <definition>int8_t * LIBC_strcpy</definition>
        <argsstring>(int8_t *dest, const int8_t *src)</argsstring>
        <name>LIBC_strcpy</name>
        <param>
          <type>int8_t *</type>
          <declname>dest</declname>
        </param>
        <param>
          <type>const int8_t *</type>
          <declname>src</declname>
        </param>
        <briefdescription>
<para>This function copies a string. </para>
        </briefdescription>
        <detaileddescription>
<para><simplesect kind="author"><para>Random</para>
</simplesect>
<simplesect kind="pre"><para>NA</para>
</simplesect>
<simplesect kind="post"><para>NA</para>
</simplesect>
<parameterlist kind="param"><parameteritem>
<parameternamelist>
<parametername direction="out">dest</parametername>
</parameternamelist>
<parameterdescription>
<para>&apos;int8_t*&apos; Represents the destination string.</para>
</parameterdescription>
</parameteritem>
<parameteritem>
<parameternamelist>
<parametername direction="in">src</parametername>
</parameternamelist>
<parameterdescription>
<para>&apos;const int8_t*&apos; Represents the string to be copied.</para>
</parameterdescription>
</parameteritem>
</parameterlist>
<simplesect kind="return"><para>&apos;int8_t&apos; Pointer to the destination string.</para>
</simplesect>
<xrefsect id="constraints_1_constraints000001"><xreftitle>Constraint</xreftitle><xrefdescription><para><itemizedlist>
<listitem><para>The destination memory area and source memory area should not overlap.</para>
</listitem><listitem><para>The destination memory area should be large enough to contain the &apos;src&apos; string.</para>
</listitem><listitem><para>The destination memory area should be in modifiable storage space and within the address space of the program.</para>
</listitem><listitem><para>The <emphasis>src</emphasis> should be a NULL terminated string.</para>
</listitem><listitem><para>The <emphasis>src</emphasis> and <emphasis>dest</emphasis> pointers should not be NULL.</para>
</listitem><listitem><para>This function is only available if FEATURE_LIBC_LEGACY_STR_ENABLED and FEATURE_LIBC_UNSAFE_STR_ENABLED symbols are defined.</para>
</listitem></itemizedlist>
</para>
</xrefdescription></xrefsect></para>
<para><xrefsect id="req_1_req000001"><xreftitle>Requirement</xreftitle><xrefdescription><para>LIBC_strcpy shall copy the string pointed by <emphasis>src</emphasis> into the array pointed by <emphasis>dest</emphasis>, including the terminating NULL character. </para>
</xrefdescription></xrefsect><xrefsect id="derived_1_derived000001"><xreftitle>Derived</xreftitle><xrefdescription><para>FALSE</para>
</xrefdescription></xrefsect></para>
<para><xrefsect id="req_1_req000002"><xreftitle>Requirement</xreftitle><xrefdescription><para>LIBC_strcpy shall return a pointer to <emphasis>dest</emphasis>. </para>
</xrefdescription></xrefsect><xrefsect id="derived_1_derived000002"><xreftitle>Derived</xreftitle><xrefdescription><para>FALSE </para>
</xrefdescription></xrefsect></para>
        </detaileddescription>
        <inbodydescription>
        </inbodydescription>
        <location file="LIBC_String.h" line="67" column="8" declfile="LIBC_String.h" declline="67" declcolumn="8"/>
      </memberdef>
      <memberdef kind="function" id="LIBC__String_8h_1affff6d4a36b7e9a48fff363785d02235" prot="public" static="no" const="no" explicit="no" inline="no" virt="non-virtual">
        <type>int8_t *</type>
        <definition>int8_t * LIBC_strcat</definition>
        <argsstring>(int8_t *dst, const int8_t *src)</argsstring>
        <name>LIBC_strcat</name>
        <param>
          <type>int8_t *</type>
          <declname>dst</declname>
        </param>
        <param>
          <type>const int8_t *</type>
          <declname>src</declname>
        </param>
        <briefdescription>
<para>This function concatenate strings. </para>
        </briefdescription>
        <detaileddescription>
<para><simplesect kind="author"><para>Random</para>
</simplesect>
<simplesect kind="pre"><para>NA</para>
</simplesect>
<simplesect kind="post"><para>NA</para>
</simplesect>
<parameterlist kind="param"><parameteritem>
<parameternamelist>
<parametername direction="out">dst</parametername>
</parameternamelist>
<parameterdescription>
<para>&apos;int8_t*&apos; Represents the string to where the characters are appended.</para>
</parameterdescription>
</parameteritem>
<parameteritem>
<parameternamelist>
<parametername direction="in">src</parametername>
</parameternamelist>
<parameterdescription>
<para>&apos;const int8_t*&apos; Represents the string from where the characters are copied.</para>
</parameterdescription>
</parameteritem>
</parameterlist>
<simplesect kind="return"><para>&apos;int8_t*&apos; Pointer to the destination string.</para>
</simplesect>
<xrefsect id="constraints_1_constraints000002"><xreftitle>Constraint</xreftitle><xrefdescription><para><itemizedlist>
<listitem><para>The destination memory area should be large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string, including the additional NULL character.</para>
</listitem><listitem><para>The destination memory area and source memory area should not overlap.</para>
</listitem><listitem><para>The destination memory area should be in modifiable storage space and within the address space of the program.</para>
</listitem><listitem><para>The <emphasis>src</emphasis> and <emphasis>dst</emphasis> pointers should not be NULL.</para>
</listitem><listitem><para>The <emphasis>src</emphasis> should be a NULL terminated string.</para>
</listitem><listitem><para>This function is only available if FEATURE_LIBC_LEGACY_STR_ENABLED and FEATURE_LIBC_UNSAFE_STR_ENABLED symbols are defined.</para>
</listitem></itemizedlist>
</para>
</xrefdescription></xrefsect></para>
<para><xrefsect id="req_1_req000003"><xreftitle>Requirement</xreftitle><xrefdescription><para>LIBC_strcat shall append the string pointed by <emphasis>src</emphasis> (including the terminating NULL character) to the end of the string pointed by <emphasis>dst</emphasis>. </para>
</xrefdescription></xrefsect><xrefsect id="derived_1_derived000003"><xreftitle>Derived</xreftitle><xrefdescription><para>FALSE</para>
</xrefdescription></xrefsect></para>
<para><xrefsect id="req_1_req000004"><xreftitle>Requirement</xreftitle><xrefdescription><para>The initial character of <emphasis>src</emphasis> shall overwrite the existing terminating NULL character of <emphasis>dst</emphasis>. </para>
</xrefdescription></xrefsect><xrefsect id="derived_1_derived000004"><xreftitle>Derived</xreftitle><xrefdescription><para>TRUE </para>
</xrefdescription></xrefsect><xrefsect id="rationale_1_rationale000001"><xreftitle>Rationale</xreftitle><xrefdescription><para>This function concatenates the src and dest strings <linebreak/>
 in a single string without any separation.</para>
</xrefdescription></xrefsect></para>
<para><xrefsect id="req_1_req000005"><xreftitle>Requirement</xreftitle><xrefdescription><para>LIBC_strcat shall return a pointer to <emphasis>dst</emphasis>.</para>
</xrefdescription></xrefsect></para>
        </detaileddescription>
        <inbodydescription>
        </inbodydescription>
        <location file="LIBC_String.h" line="111" column="8" declfile="LIBC_String.h" declline="111" declcolumn="8"/>
      </memberdef>
      </sectiondef>
    <briefdescription>
<para>This class defines several functions to manipulate C strings and memory. </para>
    </briefdescription>
    <detaileddescription>
<para><hruler/>
</para>
<para><simplesect kind="copyright"><para>Random </para>
</simplesect>
</para>
    </detaileddescription>
    <location file="LIBC_String.h"/>
  </compounddef>
</doxygen>
```

My main problem is:

- If I change the header file, the structure of the xml will change
- I have to make an application that accepts dynamic header file inputs and get the tag contents of those files

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "extracts the tags of comments inside a .h file" , can you give an example? What do you mean by "The problem is that the .xml file is dynamic which makes it difficult to read"? Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: Hi @albert. 
I'm using 1.9.4 
With different header files with different structure will the doxygen xml output be different? How can I adapt my code to every header file? Is there an external software that already does this? Is doxygen the best solution for me here or is there another parsing tool that better organize the xml file?
I added an example to clarify my problem. 
Thanks for your time

Comment: xml files have by definition a flexible format and the structure of the xml files is described in the xsd files (`index.xsd` for the master `index.xml`, `compound.xsd` for the other xml files except for the `Doxyfile.xml` which is described in `Doxyfile.xsd`,. The later is less important for you).You should probably parse the xml files by means of an xml reader or maybe it would be better to write an xslt processor file (like the very simple one given by doxygen for merging the xml files) and let the xslt processor output the required information.

Comment: Maybe you should also give some more background information why you would like to parse xml files into python classes?

Comment: @albert , to later parse it to a csv/json file, so it can be used as input to Doors.